# How to find the elements in an array that sum to an equal or lesser and closer to a given value?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I want to find the elements in a given positive integer array such that their sum is less than or equal to a given value T. When it is less than T it has to be the closest to the value of T. I hope this a variation of the subset-sum problem in dynamic programming.

For example, I have an array
A = [1, 5, 9, 11, 15] and T = 18 The answer will be element 0, 1 and 3. 
That is 1 + 5 + 11 = 17

Comment: I see, that's my oversight. Anyway, your problem is known as the 0-1 knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition

Comment: I added a comment below your answer.

Comment: This is similar to Perfect-Sum problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in `O(NS)`, where `S` is the sum of all elements in a fairly straightforward manner. While the subset-sum problem is NP-Complete, you can cache each sum you make (so you don't calculate repeated sums) for a pseudo-polynomial time solution. A simple python implementation as follows. This will return the minimum sum possible:

```py
def solve(arr, T):
    # the size of this set is bounded by S
    possible_sums = set()
    for i in arr:
        # incorporate sums from adding i to each already seen subset
        possible_sums |= {i + s for s in possible_sums}
        # just i is an additional possible subset
        possible_sums.add(i)
    # return the greatest <= T
    return max(s for s in possible_sums if s <= T)
```

Note that this will throw an error if all elements in `arr` are greater than `T`, so you just have to implement some edge case checking if that's a possible input.

Actually returning the elements in that subset gets a bit trickier, but not by much. You just have to create some link structures that let you backtrace.

```py
def solve(arr, T):
    # dictionary in the form of sum: last_index_added
    possible_sums = {}
    records = []
    # do the same as before but remember the last index
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        possible_sums = {**possible_sums, **{arr[i] + s: i for s in possible_sums}}
        possible_sums[arr[i]] = i
        records.append(possible_sums)

    # find the best sum and retrace our steps on how we got here
    best_sum = max(s for s in possible_sums if s <= T)
    record_idx = len(arr) - 1
    res = []
    while best_sum:
        last_idx = records[record_idx][best_sum]
        res.append(last_idx)
        best_sum -= arr[last_idx]
        record_idx = last_idx - 1
    return res
```

Test case:

```
>>> print(solve([1, 5, 9, 11, 15], 18))
[3, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is really good and works fine when the array length is small (~60). But when the length is ~1500, I didn't get any response even after 15 minutes and the script was killed by the OS. I think it needs some optimization.